# Drag and drop in same dataview reorder

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4.2, dataview

I've been looking for an example where one can use drag and drop within one dataview to reorder the items in that dataview.

I can't seem to find a decent example, all of them use 2 different dataviews

anybody who can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18534819/2064945).  Some things it doesn't support, such as scrolling while dragging, but it should give you a start.